# can not sign in to remote server using hostname but with ip address

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I have my remote server's `/etc/hosts` configured as:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1        localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6


169.230.xxx.xxx localhost.lab.group localhost
```

I was trying to call it from my Mac using `ssh -Y leo@localhost.lab.group`.

But after rebooting, when I try from server terminal `ssh -X leo@localhost.lab.group` it logs in fine.
But when I try the same command from my Mac it does not respond. However, if I try `ssh -Y leo@169.230.xxx.xxx` from my mac then it works fine.

Please help me out here.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to change the hostname for the server that would be used on the local network? If so, I think you can do this on the server but it would only work on the local network.

Answer (score 0):

Your mac doesn't resolve your remote server's `/etc/hosts` unless you are already signed into the server using ssh. Before you log in, you are resolving through whatever your mac uses to resolve (possibly a hosts file, I'm not familiar with that aspect of OSX).

If the server is on your local network, you can resolve through a local resolver, usually on your router. Sometimes, the local resolver will honor hostnames set by the server. Other times, you have to set local host names on the router or local resolver.

You can use the following command on the server to show your current hostname:

```
hostnamectl
```

If you want to set or change the hostname for your server to use on your local network, you can use the following command:

```
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname localhost.lab.group
```

This assumes that you want to set the host name for your server to "localhost.lab.group" and this will be the hostname or "machine name" used on your local network. Most of the time this will work. Other times, you will have to also set this domain name for the server through your router settings or with the network administrator.

If you are not on your local network, I think you would have to register a domain name so that other DNS servers will assign the domain name to your address. Alternatively, you could do this through your OSX settings but I'm not sure how to do that.

[more info on linuxize.com](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-change-hostname-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

Comment: This also does not help. I tried a website to see if it can resolve my ip using `localhost.lab.group` and it worked. The IP was correct. I don't understand why connection from my mac does not work even both of them are on the same network.

Comment: @abhisek If both are on your local network, it's possible your mac isn't using the local resolver or it's possible you have no local resolver. The problem you're having appears to be on the client side (mac) or the network side, not the server side. Does your mac have a hosts file? Questions about OSX don't are off topic here but I think your host file is `/private/etc/hosts` on OSX. Just add the same line to your OSX host file and you should be good probably after your restart networking.

Comment: @abhisek If you need a better understanding, check out [this related question and the answers that follow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16901/70847), however, it should be noted that one answer mentions dhclient which you can ignore as `cat /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf | grep "send host-name"` should return `send host-name = gethostname();` on your server (that answer is kind of old and this is how it should look).

Comment: @abhisek So, you need to set the line `169.230.xxx.xxx localhost.lab.group localhost` on the hosts file of your mac computer or however that is done on OSX or you should talk to your network administrator about resolving local host names through whatever the local network uses (usually in the router settings).

Comment: @abhisek If you set the hosts file on OSX, you shouldn't have to deal with the network admin though. And if the `hostnamectl`  command returns `localhost.lab.group` on your server and `cat /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf | grep "send host-name"` returns `send host-name = gethostname();` on your server, then it looks like you've done all you need to do on the server.

Comment: @abhisek If you need help with OSX, questions about apple are on topic over at https://unix.stackexchange.com and also https://apple.stackexchange.com/